# Ionic Cordova to Capacitor, using cordova resorces icons and spash images

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have an app in Ionic with cordova that contains a resources folder with all the icons and splash screens inside this folder which is on the app root.
It also contains the config.xml with the image paths etc.

My problem is that I'm rewriting this app using Ionic / Capacitor.
I've pasted the resources folder in the root and the config.xml. 
I've then run the application but get no icons or splash screens from the resources folder.

How can I get my icons and splash images to work on my Ionic Capacitor version of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate resources by hand or with online services like:

https://appicon.co/#app-icon

http://nsimage.brosteins.com/

For android put your resources file inside:

APP-ROOT/android/app/src/main/res

For Ios follow this guide:

https://guides.codepath.com/ios/adding-image-assets

*Unfortunately there are no commands like in cordova*

Comment: The thing is that I've already got all the images already cropped...just don't know how to make the app use them